# Terminal zsh: command not found: svnserve

Tags: zsh, svnserve

The Apple book has been able to view the version of svnserve, M1 chip computer through the terminal after entering the command prompt zsh: command not found: svnserve。If there are seniors who have encountered this problem, they can give some advice。Thank you!!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  On the new M1 based Mac, have you ensured that you have installed svnserve?  Also - you might need to install it via Rosetta 2 - a good primer can be found here - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407731/how-does-rosetta-2-work

Comment: Once you have verified that `svnserve` exists and is executable, make sure that its directory is in the PATH, or invoke it by specifying the directory explicitly.